# How to update context state inside componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have difficulty applying Reduce to my project, I used context.

I've created a global context.
I want to change the global context tid in componentDidMount.

Please help me to make a change.

> GlobalContext.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

export class GlobalProvider extends Component {
    setTermId = process_id => {
            this.setState('0');
    };
    state = {
        userId: 'pvd-userid',
        tId: 'pvd-tid'

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <GlobalContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </GlobalContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

> ViewTem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from '../GlobalContext';


class ViewTem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let cols = ['cc9900', 'cc0023'];
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/tview',{method:'POST', headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},body:{color: cols}});
        const conId = await res.text();
        /*
         * I want to put the 'conId' in the 'context.tid' and see the changes in the dev console and body.
        */
        console.log(' this.context:', this.context.tId);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                connect id : 
                <GlobalContext.Consumer>
                    {value => value.userName}
                </GlobalContext.Consumer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ViewTem.contextType = GlobalContext;

export default ViewTem;
```

The app.js code below shows only the part of the context delivery method.

> app.js

```
....
<GlobalProvider>
    <App/>
</GlobalProvider>
....
```

It seems difficult for beginners to understand the context example of the react homepage.
It also confuses things like duplication of names such as state and function.

Is there a simple code example that is easy to understand?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this code once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-axjwa5 , let me know if you're unclear about it , happy to help you then

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers.
The implementation of Coyp-Hello.js works fine.
I have just started react, so I need to understand some more code that I have noticed.
I can see the query code here(https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dy1bwf).
Sorry, can you give me a clearer answer?
What I want is to change the value of tid to "ctx-tid" in componentDidMount and use it for all components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, it's a bad idea to mutate `this.state` directly, as subsequent updates may overwrite your changes. This applies just as much if you're accessing that state via a context!

The [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) recommends also passing an updater function as part of the value, which will call `setState` on the component that owns the provider.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

export class GlobalProvider extends Component {
    setTermId = tId => {
        this.setState({ tId });
    };

    state = {
        userId: 'pvd-userid',
        tId: 'pvd-tid',
        setTermId: this.setTermId,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <GlobalContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </GlobalContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

You can then update the state by calling that function in your consuming component.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I tried to use redux, but it was so difficult that I chose context api.
I can use the changes in the component, but I need to use the updated tid in ViewTem.js in the whole application.
So I tried to change the value of context.tid.

Is there any way to change to setState ()?
If time permits, can you confirm it here(stackblitz.com/edit/react-dy1bwf )?

Comment: Here is [a working version of your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vthsev) - note that `this.context` was [added in React 16.6](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html), and your example was using 16.5, so I had to upgrade it.

Comment: Note also that there are some limitations to `this.context` - the main one being that your component will only be able to read one context type, even if it's nested within multiple contexts. If that doesn't fit your needs, you'll need to use the `Consumer` API instead.

Comment: I have just started React, and I feel that it is lacking in many parts.
I searched a lot before commenting, and your comments certainly helped.
I am very grateful to you for your help.
@joeClay

Comment: Glad I could help! If you're just starting, I'd recommend not delving too deep into contexts/Redux/etc. yet - for a lot of apps, just using components and passing around props is sufficient. It's when this approach becomes cumbersome that you should reach for stuff like the Context API. I'd recommend reading [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) if you've not already!

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
There is a lot of problems to apply to projects without sufficient study.
But over time, it seems to be solved.
I am late but thank you again for your help.